# Summarising same column twice with dplyr return NA

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Consider the following minimal working example in R:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
  colour=c('red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'),
  value=c(1, 1, 2, 2)
)

df %>%
  group_by(colour) %>%
  summarise(
    value=mean(value),
    value.sd=sd(value),
  )
```

The output is

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  colour value value.sd
  <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 blue       2       NA
2 red        1       NA
```

when the expected output is

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  colour      value value.sd
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 blue            2        0
2 red             1        0
```

I know how to work around the issue. As the following code will provide the expected output:

```
df %>%
  group_by(colour) %>%
  summarise(
    value.mean=mean(value),
    value.sd=sd(value),
  )
```

My question is: am I using R/dplyr wrongly in the first code sample or this a bug in dplyr?

Comment: I think the problem is that you're changing `value` to a single number (the mean) and then trying to take the standard deviation of a single number. If you calculate sd before changing the value of `value` it works as expected, i.e. `df %>% group_by(colour) %>% summarise(value.sd=sd(value), value=mean(value))`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @jared_mamrot. So I don't know R enough. :-D In my mind, variable names would be isolated. In the call `summarise(v1=f(v2), v3=f(v4))`, `v2` and `v4` will be lazy evaluated in the scope of column names of the data input and would not clash with `v1` and `v3` that will be used as name for the output columns.

Comment: There are very few people who 'know R enough' - I'm certainly still learning - but I highly recommend reading https://adv-r.hadley.nz/ to get a better understanding of evaluation (and R in general). In your example v2 and v4 don't clash, but `summarise(v1=f(v2), v3=f(v1))` is problematic. The [source code for `summarise()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/R/summarise.R) also shows that things are more complicated than they first seem (i.e. quosures/non-standard-evaluation/etc). Regardless, I'm glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran you code I got a warning that data_frame was deprecated.

This works

```
df <- tibble(
    colour=c('red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'),
    value=c(1, 1, 2, 2)
)

df %>%
    group_by(colour) %>%
    summarise(
        value.mean = mean(value),
        value.sd=sd(value)
    )
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  colour value.mean value.sd
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 blue            2        0
2 red             1        0
```

So I would suggest trying that because maybe there was a bug that was fixed.